# how to rewrite only 2 folders htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

everyone.
I need to redirect only 2 folders:

```
example.com/foo/
example.com/bar
```

to

```
example.com/index.php?i=foo
example.com/index.php?i=bar
```

my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/foo/$ /index.php?i=foo [L]
RewriteRule ^/bar/$ /index.php?i=bar [L]
```

But i still get 404, when i open /foo/ or /bar/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the leading forward slashes:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^foo/?$ index.php?i=foo [L]
RewriteRule ^bar/?$ index.php?i=bar [L]
```

I have also made the trailing slash on the directory name optional.